# C API Design Questions - function names and semantics

Tags: c, api

I am working on redesigning a simple C API interface for controlling a piece of hardware.

I have several questions that are all related to the API. I'm not sure if I should group them all in this question or submit multiple questions. For now I will list them all here.

For reference the API is structured in the following style.

```
LIB_ERR_CODE myfunction1(int param1);
```

My questions:

1. Is it more appropriate to have a function for Enable and Disable OR a single Enable function with a bool parameter?

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE EnableOscillator(int device);
   LIB_ERR_CODE DisableOscillator(int device);
   ```

   vs

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE EnableOscillator(int device, bool bEnable);
   ```
2. I want to unify the naming scheme. Below is some examples of the terms used. What are the preferred terms are?

   Example 1:

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE SetTemperature(int value);    // set temperature
   LIB_ERR_CODE GetTemperature(int *pvalue);  // returns actual temperature
   ```

   Example 2:

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE ProgramHumidity(int value); // set humidity
   LIB_ERR_CODE ReadHumidity(int *pvalue);  // returns actual humidity
   ```

   Example 3:

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE WriteConfiguration(int value);   // write values to a config register
   LIB_ERR_CODE ReadConfiguration(int *pvalue);  // reads values from the config register
   LIB_ERR_CODE CurrentConfiguration(int *pvalue); // Current configuration values
   ```

This is a piece of hardware I am communicating with so it makes sense to me for there to be three complementing functions. A function to set the value, a function to read back the set value, a function to read the actual value.

3. Is it logical to combine two function calls which are required to make 1 hardware feature operate? To set up the oscillator the following functions must be called (order doesn't matter).

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE ProgramFrequency(int freq);
   LIB_ERR_CODE ProgramAmplitude(int amp);
   ```

   I feel it would make more sense to combine them.

   ```
   LIB_ERR_CODE ProgramOscillator(int freq, int amp);
   ```

Comment: You'll note the close votes: "primarily opinion based". Some languages have something approaching a universal style guide -- for example, most Java teams at least stick to capitalisation standards. With C, there's no such thing. You could adopt the style guide of a particular project - (maybe GNU), but there's no One True Way.

Comment: Referring 2: Setter and Getters are commonly named `Set*()`/`Get*()`. I personally preferred it the other way round `*Set()`/`*Get()`, as this sorts more nicely ... :-)

Comment: Referring the 1st question: Since the invention of the excruciating `EnableWindow()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291(v=vs.85).aspx) some 25 years ago, unfortunately the latter is the more common.

Comment: For the 3rd, I'd provide all three, implementing the last as wrapper around the two former.

Comment: Anyway, do as you feel is best, just document everything well.

Comment: I tend to favor readability over useless abstractions. See fefe on [API design](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/diet.pdf) (slide 21): Bad: `int fd=open("foo",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0600);` Good: `int fd=open_write("foo");`